# Trouble searching for deleted cases

Tags: civicase, search

In Civi 5.5.3 (Drupal 7.59) I'm running into an error trying to search for deleted cases. In case search with our without additional parameters set, if I check the "Deleted Cases" box I get an error page (generic HTTP 500 page).

In the system logs I get this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'TASK_DELETE' in /mysite/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Form/Search.php on line 180, referer: mysite.org/civicrm/case/search?reset=1
```

I'm unable to replicate this on the Demo site because I could only find a 5.3.1 Demo. There is deleted case bug on 5.3.1 but that is a different behavior and has a fix that has already been implemented in 5.5.3 https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/commit/2ff620ae263a6c7430730d9b59261ec2b400b063

I need a little help tracking down why the TASK_DELETE is undefined.

The search works in 4.6.38 and I can see the buildQuickForm function was being re-jiggered in the Search file starting in 4.7. (From 5.0 and up it looks just as it does in 5.5.3)

```
  public function buildQuickForm() {
    parent::buildQuickForm();
    $this->addSortNameField();

    CRM_Case_BAO_Query::buildSearchForm($this);

    $rows = $this->get('rows');
    if (is_array($rows)) {
      if (!$this->_single) {
        $this->addRowSelectors($rows);
      }

      $tasks = CRM_Case_Task::permissionedTaskTitles(CRM_Core_Permission::getPermission());

      if (!empty($this->_formValues['case_deleted'])) {
        unset($tasks[CRM_Case_Task::TASK_DELETE]);
      }
      else {
        unset($tasks[CRM_Case_Task::RESTORE_CASES]);
      }

      $this->addTaskMenu($tasks);
    }

  }
```

In the Case > Task.php file, I see the TASK_DELETE

```
class CRM_Case_Task extends CRM_Core_Task {

...

public static function tasks() {
        if (!self::$_tasks) {
          self::$_tasks = array(
            self::TASK_DELETE => array(
              'title' => ts('Delete cases'),
              'class' => 'CRM_Case_Form_Task_Delete',
              'result' => FALSE,
            ),
...
```

Is there some formatting error I'm overlooking? Does anyone else get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in CRM_Core_Task, not CRM_Case_Task, so that reference in buildQuickForm maybe should be CRM_Core_Task::TASK_DELETE. I'm not sure off the top of my head how php handles static inheritance for constants. It might be a difference with your version of php, since it seems to work on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org.

Comment: You're totally right, I swapped out Core for Case in the CRM and it works. I didn't know it would be related to my PHP version. (We are on PHP 5.6.26, testing through Civi 5 so we can move to PHP 7.1)

Comment: Thank you for the link to the most recent Civi Demo (I was at https://civicrm.org/demo trying to find something.)